# Type conversion to another class with namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, type-conversion

Normally, one could write a conversion operator to convert to another class like

```
struct A {};

struct B
{
    operator A()
    {
        return A();
    } 
};
```

Now, what if `A` struct has a namespace different than `B`:

```
namespace mars {
struct A {};
}

namespace jupiter {
struct B
{
    operator A()  //??
    {
        return A();
    } 
};
}
```

What should the `operator A()` statement become?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply fully qualify the names

```
namespace mars {
  struct A {};
}

namespace jupiter {
  struct B
  {
    operator mars::A()
    {
      return mars::A();
    } 
  };
}
```

As a suggestion: try not to do something like

```
using namespace mars;
```

in the global scope: that would pollute it and render things more complex when the application grows (e.g. name clashing). **Especially** for the `std` namespace, it is often more desirable to fully qualify names to avoid this phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

The operator should become:

```
namespace jupiter {
struct B
{
    operator mars::A()
    {
        return mars::A();
    } 
};
}
```